# Should I Clear Timeout in a Function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

Do i need to clear the timeout when doing this code below?
I know that you need to clear it when using it in `useEffect`. But do you need to clear it when you want to delay something after submitting?

```
 let timer = null

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearTimeout(timer)
  }, [])

const onSubmit = () => {
  dispatch(
    submitProduct({
      payload,
      successCallback: () => {
        setOpenSnackbar(true);
        setSelectedDetails({
          content: `Success`,
          status: "success",
        });
        timer = setTimeout(() => onCloseModal(), 1000);
      },
      errorCallback: () => {
        setOpenSnackbar(true);
        setSelectedDetails({
          content: `Error`,
          status: "error",
        });
      },
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: If your action is not supposed to run after the component has unmounted, you should clean it up regardless. If you are triggering a state update on an unmounted component, that is in indication of memory leak, so best practice is to clear it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, timer is a normal variable so it will be reset to null on every render. So here you better use a ref otherwise the cleanup is useless

Here is how you can do it using a `ref`:

```
const timer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearTimeout(timer.current)
  }, [])

const onSubmit = () => {
  dispatch(
    submitProduct({
      payload,
      successCallback: () => {
        setOpenSnackbar(true);
        setSelectedDetails({
          content: `Success`,
          status: "success",
        });
        timer.current = setTimeout(() => onCloseModal(), 1000);
      },
      errorCallback: () => {
        setOpenSnackbar(true);
        setSelectedDetails({
          content: `Error`,
          status: "error",
        });
      },
    })
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a ref, you don't depend on the functional component lifecycle.

Edit: oops, same answer as above. However, you should add a check if the timeoutRef is defined.

```
  const timeoutRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => timeoutRef.current && clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current); // To be sure it's not undefined
  }, [])

const onSubmit = () => {
  dispatch(
    submitProduct({
      payload,
      successCallback: () => {
        setOpenSnackbar(true);
        setSelectedDetails({
          content: `Success`,
          status: "success",
        });
        timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => onCloseModal(), 1000);
      },
      errorCallback: () => {
        setOpenSnackbar(true);
        setSelectedDetails({
          content: `Error`,
          status: "error",
        });
      },
    })
  );
};
```